# [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project]by calling firebase.app()

Tags: react-native

This is the error that I get.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project]by calling firebase.app().]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be using firebase for web. If so, use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) instead.